# Algorithm exam example for the 2nd largest value in the list

Tags: algorithm, list, pseudocode

the exam question is this:

> A common operation on a list is to find the “largest” value in a list.  Write an algorithm which will find the “second largest” value in a list. You can assume that the list will contain at least 2 values and that no value is duplicated.  Do not write C# code as your answer, but the algorithm should be at a level of detail that would lend itself to implementation in C# or any other programming language.
>
> The algorithm should not make use of any supplied functionality, e.g.
>   C# Array class methods such as Sort etc. It is also assumed that this
>   algorithm would be implemented as a method which returns the location
>   of the second largest value of the list and that the order of the
>   values within the list is unchanged. This means that one cannot simply
>   sort the array in ascending order and return (`list.Length-2`) as it is
>   assume that the list will be passed by reference to this method.

I answered this as:

```
1)  define integer variables as i and j
2)  assume listValues is the list of values
3)  create a new list called values which is equal to listValues
4)  create a new list called largest
5)  i is equal to 0, j is equal to list length of “values” list
6)  a while loop which is:
    a)  while 1 <  j
    b)  if values[0] > values[j-1]:
        1)  new integer k, k = 0
        2)  while k < j - 1
            a)largest = largest + values[k]
            b)k = k + 1
        3)  values = largest
        4)  largest = empty list
    c) else: 
        1)  new integer l, l = j – 1
        2)  while l > 0
            a) largest = largest + values[l] 
            b) l = l – 1
        3)  values = largest
        4)  largest = empty list
7)  a while loop which is :
    a)  while i < j
    b)  if values[0] not equal to listValues[i]
        1)  largest = largest + listValues[i]
    c)  i = i + 1
8)  listValues = largest
9)  values = listValues
10)  largest = empty 
11) a while loop which is:
    a)  while 1 <  j
    b)  if values[0] > values[j-1]:
        1)  new integer k, k = 0
        2)  while k < j - 1
            a)  largest = largest + values[k]
            b)  k = k + 1
        3)  values = largest
        4)  largest = empty list
    c) else: 
        1)  new integer l, l = j – 1
        2)  while l > 0
            a)  largest = largest + values[l] 
            b)  l = l – 1
        3)  values = largest
        4)  largest = empty list
12)  return values[0]
```

I know that's inefficent I could just add another loop outside of the loop between 6 and 9 but considering my exam is gonna be paper based it would be pretty hard to edit, so therefore I did it like this. But my concern is if this answer is true or not. I'd be glad if someone checks.

Comment: What is your question for the SO audience?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in `O(n)` the same way like finding the largest element. Just keep two variables - the largest found and the second largest found element. Think about how to update these two variables when you iterate through the list.

Answer (score 0):

in C

```
   int second_largest(int *arr, size_t len) {
      int i, j, k;
      assert(len > 1);
      k = (arr[0] > arr[1]) ? 0 : 1;
      i = arr[k];
      j = arr[1 - k];
      for (k = 2; k < len; k++)
      {
         if (arr[k] > i) { j = i;
                           i = arr[k]; }   
         else if (arr[k] > j) { j = arr[k]; }
      }
      return j;
   }
```

Comment: I have edited your post, because you have missed to check, `if (arr[k] > j)`. `arr[k]` can be between `i` and `j`(smaller than `i`, but larger than `j`).